# Issue with app.EnterText for Android API 29 ONLY Xamarin.UITest

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I have been having an issue with Xamarin.UITest after the application that I am working on was updated to the latest android version (API 29). This issue did not happen before the application updates and automation worked as intended on API 29. Before the application was updated and you did a fresh install the application would have an "OS" prompt stating that the "Application was out of Date" once the application was updated that prompt no longer displayed however the Xamarin.UITest issues appeared.

The issue is that when automation runs on a device with API 29 ONLY and when the code app.EnterText runs the text that was requested via code to be inputted does not get input. The same applies to app.ClearText, once the command is done the text in the field does not get cleared. its as if there is a permission issue with the automation interacting with the application text fields only. Note, the test does not fail with an error and the test keeps running like it did the commend, which makes it header to know why it's doing this.

I did work with my DEV's to see if this is an application issue and his theory is that it's a permission issue but we are both not sure where the issue is of what permission is being blocked any help of shedding light would be very helpful.

Environment replication that I am seeing the issues on:

Device/OS: Pixel 3 XL (real device)/ Android version 10(API 29)

Xamarin.UITest version: 3.0.4

Application:

Rinning the latest updates for packages including Xamrin.Forms and the application is configured for API(29)

Note: the text fields work just fine outside of automation and if a user inputs the text it works as intended, just an Automation issue

VS/Xcode version:

Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 for Mac

Version 8.3.10 (build 2)

Installation UUID: 87bfc8d6-bb7e-4416-8725-c451ad424835

GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

Xamarin.Mac 5.16.1.24 (d16-3 / 08809f5b)

Package version: 604000208
Mono Framework MDK

Runtime:

Mono 6.4.0.208 (2019-06/07c23f2ca43) (64-bit)

Package version: 604000208

NuGet

Version: 5.3.0.6192

.NET Core SDK

SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Sdks

SDK Versions:

3.0.100

2.1.700

2.1.505

2.1.504

2.1.503

2.1.302

2.1.301

2.1.4

MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.4.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Core Runtime

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet

Runtime Versions:

3.0.0

2.1.13

2.1.11

2.1.9

2.1.8

2.1.7

2.1.2

2.1.1

2.0.5

Xamarin.Profiler

Version: 1.6.12.29

Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater

Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools

Xcode 11.2.1 (15526.1)

Build 11B500

Xamarin Designer

Version: 16.3.0.256

Hash: 8a223bfd7

Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3

Build date: 2019-11-01 21:02:02 UTC

Xamarin.Mac

Version: 6.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Enterprise)

Hash: e3c2b406d

Branch: xcode11.2

Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:07-0400

Xamarin.iOS

Version: 13.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Enterprise)

Hash: e3c2b406d

Branch: xcode11.2

Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:08-0400

Xamarin.Android

Version: 10.0.6.2 (Visual Studio Enterprise)

Commit: xamarin-android/d16-3/c407838

Android SDK: /Users/{*}/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx

Supported Android versions:

5.0 (API level 21)

5.1 (API level 22)

6.0 (API level 23)

7.0 (API level 24)

7.1 (API level 25)

8.0 (API level 26)

8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1

SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.5

SDK Build Tools Version: 28.0.3

Build Information:

Mono: mono/mono/2019-06@476d72b9e32

Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-3@5836f58

LibZipSharp: grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-3@71f4a94

LibZip: nih-at/libzip/rel-1-5-1@b95cf3fd

ProGuard: xamarin/proguard/master@905836d

SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.27.1@8212a2d

Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-3@cb41333

Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK

Java SDK: /Users/mmoadeb/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25

1.8.0-25

Android Designer EPL code available here:

https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager

Version: 1.4.0.65

Hash: c33b107

Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3

Build date: 2019-11-19 20:33:22 UTC

Android Device Manager

Version: 1.2.0.116

Hash: d2b2af0

Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3

Build date: 2019-11-19 20:33:42 UTC

Xamarin Inspector

Version: 1.4.3

Hash: db27525

Branch: 1.4-release

Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT

Client compatibility: 1

Build Information

Release ID: 803100002

Git revision: add3a4998a5cb5b081e0404e1fe13acfecb7801d

Build date: 2019-11-20 13:35:15+00

Build branch: release-8.3

Xamarin extensions: 79c69708816813b498283eeda7bcb4d464433a04

Operating System

Mac OS X 10.15.1

Darwin 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0

Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019

root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Enabled user installed extensions

Straight8's SpecFlow Integration 1.11.3.0

XAML Styler 1.1.5

The only error that I see when debugging the test is below, I am not sure if this has any relevance:
'''
[0x7000100bc000] The instruction pointer of the currently executing method(Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery:tokensFromObjectArray (object[])) is not on the recorded stack. This is likely due to a runtime bug. The 15 frames are as follow:

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (0 / 15): (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (1 / 15): System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo)

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (2 / 15): System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke (object,object[])

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (3 / 15): System.Delegate:DynamicInvokeImpl (object[])

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (4 / 15): System.MulticastDelegate:DynamicInvokeImpl (object[])

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (5 / 15): System.Delegate:DynamicInvoke (object[])

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (6 / 15): TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker:InvokeBinding (TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.IBinding,TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.IContextManager,object[],TechTalk.SpecFlow.Tracing.ITestTracer,System.TimeSpan&)

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (7 / 15): TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine:ExecuteStepMatch (TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingMatch,object[])

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (8 / 15): TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine:ExecuteStep (TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.IContextManager,TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.StepInstance)

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (9 / 15): TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine:Step (TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.StepDefinitionKeyword,string,string,string,TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (10 / 15): TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner:When (string,string,TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table,string)

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (11 / 15): TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps:When (string,string,TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (12 / 15): TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps:When (string)

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (13 / 15): WellRx.UITests.Steps.DashboardSteps:GivenIAmOnTheHomePage ()

[0x7000100bc000] Frame (14 / 15): (wrapper dynamic-method) object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.IContextManager)
'''

Comment: For those who have the same issue, I opened a bug here https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/1451 with the Xamarin team

Comment: Have you tried updating to v3.0.5?

Comment: @Saamer I have and the issue is still open on v3.0.5

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to play around with the Options->General->Target framework & Options->Android Application->Target android version?

Comment: @Saamer I built the application with the targeted version being 9 and not 10 and the issue was still present so that does not appear to be the issue.